# External form in wordpress web site

Tags: wordpress, forms, custom-wordpress-pages

I have built a form with html/css/js/php and I need to use in a wordpress site but only a customer user can see the form.How can i control if a user is loged in?(session or cookie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a built in function to detect if a user is logged in - [is_user_logged_in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).

You could use it like this.

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) :
    // show form
else :
    // Hide form, give other message etc.
endif;
```